# Instagram API: Downloading images linked to a hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My team needs to download images linked to a hashtag on Instagram. However, it seems that this is not allowed via the Instagram API as the user that posted the image needs to give permission first. This is not a good user experience for the app that needs to be built. Does anyone know of an alternative way to get around this?

Comment: go to instagram.com and search hashtag and download

Comment: I need to do this via the API